PyTesseract not extracting text?
Pytesseract does not extract the text from the image. The terminal stays black with a space as if it was actually trying to extract the text.
Here is my code and the image:
from PIL import Image 
import pytesseract
import cv2
"C:\\Users\\Emiliano\\Downloads\\practic.png"
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd="C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

img=cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Emiliano\\Downloads\\practic.png')
cv2.imshow('window', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)


well changed the code a bit and now the output its just a black space

What does this practic.png look like? Please show it in your question.

The backslashes in your code are not escaped. Maybe this might be the reason.

Now that the backslashes are fixed: There is nothing wrong with the code. It works perfectly. Can you upload the image? I am pretty sure that this is the actual problem, but tesseract offers a lot of parameters to categorize your image.

Just making sure -- you're aware that waitKey(0) will stop the process until you press a key?
